# Clone Android object using serialization

Tags: android, serialization, clone

I need to clone an object I have created (a custom class).
Cloning it using the standard object.clone would be messy since it includes references to other objects and it would require me to clone those too.

I read that one way to clone it would be to serialize the object and then de-serialize it.

Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, serialization is used to send objects off somewhere (into a file or over the network) so that somebody else can reconstruct them later. But you can abuse it to reconstruct the object yourself immediately. If the object is serializable at all, then the reconstruction should be a faithful copy.

But this technique is not to be used lightly. First of all, serialization is hugely expensive. It could easily be a hundred times more expensive than the clone() method. Secondly, not all objects are serializable. Thirdly, making a class serializable is tricky and not all classes can be relied on to get it right. (You can assume that system classes are correct, though.) So I believe it's not a good idea.

Comment: My object is already defined as Serializable for the purposes of saving. What sort of overhead are we talking about? My program is a game and the cloning will need to be performed once each time the program has to make its move. Helps me run "what-if" scenarios on the data.

Comment: A major cost of implementing Serializable is that it decreases the flexibility
to change a class’s implementation once it has been released. When a
class implements Serializable, its byte-stream encoding (or serialized form)
becomes part of its exported API. Once you distribute a class widely, you are generally
required to support the serialized form forever, just as you are required to
support all other parts of the exported API.

Comment: A second cost of implementing Serializable is that it increases the likelihood
of bugs and security holes. Normally, objects are created using constructors;
serialization is an extralinguistic mechanism for creating objects.

Comment: It also increases the testing
burden associated with releasing a new version of a class. When a serializable
class is revised, it is important to check that it is possible to serialize an instance in
the new release and deserialize it in old releases, and vice versa.

Comment: I will be serializing and deserializing immediately in order to create the copy. I am not carrying over from one version to the next since it is all within the same run.

Comment: just look on clone() and serealization efficient in table  "Milliseconds to deep copy a simple class graph n times" : http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip76.html?page=2

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware the serialization adds overhead, a massive overhead compared to direct cloning. You also have to make sure that every member of your class (and in turn every member of every field, ...) needs to be serializable. I would prefer adding a proper clone() implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You write:

> Cloning it using the standard
>   object.clone would be messy since it
>   includes references to other objects
>   and it would require me to clone those
>   too.

When you do the cloning via Serialization you either

- need to serialize those other objects too (otherwise the resulting object is no real clone)
- accept that the clone will be partial (without referenced objects).

In the later case, you can just implement a `clone()` method that leaves the other objects out.

Aside for the cost of Serialization, TANSTAAFL